# how to setup sqlite database in quarkus framework

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, kotlin, quarkus

I have problem with setting sqlite with quarkus .
can anyone help me?
It appears that quarkus does not support sqlite .

and my application.properties file is :

```
quarkus.datasource.ergoint.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=sqlite
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlite:/home/user/myProject/testSqlite.db
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=4
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to
> errors    [error]: Build step
> io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception:
> io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to
> determine the driver for default datasource   at
> io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.resolveDriver(AgroalProcessor.java:391)
> at

Comment: Have you included a dependency to the `org.sqlite.JDBC` driver? e.g. `org.xerial:sqlite-dialect:3.30.1`

Comment: There's a section in the Quakus docs about using databases other than those with built-in support: https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#other-databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panache and hibernate don't support Sqlite so I had to use JDBC and write SQL query . :<

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `db-kind` to `other` and you need to set the JDBC driver.
I think you should also define your own SQLDialect if you want to use Hibernate.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=my.project.SQLDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlite:/home/user/myProject/testSqlite.db
quarkus.datasource.username=sa
quarkus.datasource.password=sa
```